# Authelia with nginx proxy, username and group empty

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I've been trying to set up a test environment for Authelia to protect a website for weeks. I'm attempting to do everything on a single machine, but I've also tried on different machines. When I access the website, I'm redirected to authenticate with Authelia. After what seems like a successful authentication, the browser attempts to go to the endpoint but returns to the Authelia login screen. Here's a snippet of the logs where it seems the issue lies in the Nginx proxy configuration, as the username and group appear empty.

on authelia.log

level=debug msg="Check authorization of subject username= groups=

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.